# Cumulative sum with condition

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I wish to derive cumulative column based on initially adding the daily amount to the `Value`, then subsequently adding the daily amount to the resulting figure.

Could you please help, thanks.

| Date | Type | Value | Rate | Cummulative |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 29/04/2022 | A | 128.61 | 32.00 | 256.61 |
| 28/04/2022 | A | 128.61 | 32.00 | 224.61 |
| 27/04/2022 | A | 128.61 | 32.00 | 192.61 |
| 26/04/2022 | A | 128.61 | 32.00 | 160.61 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the example script below. Once reloaded the `CumulativeData` table will contain new column `Cumulative` which will be the result.

The "magic" is happening in the following expression:

```
if(RecNo() = 1, 
     Value + Rate, 
     peek(Cumulative) + Rate
) as Cumulative
```

In the expression we are saying:

- if the record number is 1 (first row of the table) then sum `Value` and `Rate` values. This is our "base" and we'll accumulate to this value
- for the next rows get the above (previous row) value of `Cumulative` column (`peek(Cumulative)`) and add the current row `Rate` value

More about `peek` function can be found at the [documentation page](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2021/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/InterRecordFunctions/Peek.htm)

Example script:

```
RawData:
Load * Inline [
Date      , Type,   Value , Rate
29/04/2022, A   ,   128.61, 32.00
28/04/2022, A   ,   128.61, 32.00
27/04/2022, A   ,   128.61, 32.00
26/04/2022, A   ,   128.61, 32.00
];

// Dont foget to order the table in ascending order
CumulativeData:
Load 
  *,
  if(RecNo() = 1, 
       Value + Rate, 
       peek(Cumulative) + Rate
  ) as Cumulative
Resident
  RawData
Order By
  Date ASC
;

Drop Table RawData;
```

Result table:

[image: Result table]

Comment: Hi @Stefan Stoichev I omiited an essential part of my requirement, that's why a type has multiple IDs. Could you kindly help me factor this in the initial solution you provided.       
 Date     Type  ID                    Value  Rate Cumulative
     
29/04/2022 A A2126334530 408.36 1.77         410.13
29/04/2022 A A2126394105 3,610.75 16.05 3,626.80
29/04/2022 A A2126584230 4,654.73 22.06 4,676.79
29/04/2022 A A2130920480 10,107.63 60.16 10,167.79
29/04/2022 A A2204715054 4,824.64 73.10 4,897.74

Comment: if you add the `ID` column to the `Order By`? `... Order By Date, ID ASC ...`